# Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page Dotnetnuke 6.2 Error

Tags: dotnetnuke-6, dotnetnuke-module

Hi all I am developing a portal in dotnetnuke 6.2. I am developing custom modules for the project.I am using ajax controls in ascx files for the module development.but when running the application it shows **Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page** error.But no where i am using script manager in the project.I searched the on the web.No exact solution is available.Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the Default.aspx.cs page on the root of your DotNetNuke website you can see:

```
var scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);
if (scriptManager == null)
{
  scriptManager = new ScriptManager();
  Page.Form.Controls.AddAt(0, scriptManager);
}
```

The ScriptManager is on the main page of DotNetNuke...